# android - how to access button object in multiple functions if declared in onCreate()

Tags: java, android

we are making BINGO game in which we have 25 buttons, I have created their objects and an array to store them. Now I need to access those button objects in more than one function. Where do I exactly declare those button's objects ? Also I have defined all function in my class, after onCreate(). I need to access those button objects in show(),acceptNum(),client_row(), where and how should I declare it? Please help!

```
public class bingo extends AppCompatActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bingo);
}
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button b10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button b11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    Button b12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    Button b13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    Button b14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
    Button b15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
    Button b16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
    Button b17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18);
    Button b18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
    Button b19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button20);
    Button b20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
    Button b21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);
    Button b22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
    Button b23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button24);
    Button b24 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button25);
    Button b25 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button26);

    Button butt[] = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, 
 b14, b15, b16, b17, b18, b19, b20, b21, b22, b23, b24, b25};

public void show()
{...}

public void acceptNum()
{...}

public void client_row()
{...}

}

}//closing class
```

Comment: declare it outside the method, instantiate it inside of it

Comment: What are you planning to do with the `Button`s in those methods `show()`,`acceptNum()` and `client_row()`?

Answer (score 1):

You declare your button outside the onCreate and initialize it inside the OnCreate :

```
public class bingo extends AppCompatActivity{
Button b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bingo);

     b1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}



public void show()
{...}

public void acceptNum()
{...}

public void client_row()
{...}


}//closing class
```

Comment: I can do the same for array right? Because it's giving me error at butt[ ]={...}; as unexpected token near [ ]. But there's no error there!

Comment: yep, you should declare your array outside after you declare all your buttons

Comment: hey it's not working! the app crashes when i access those buttons from show()

Comment: i have accessed it in XML file using onClick()="show".

Comment: I thiink you should learn more about android, and start by following tutorials, before beginning your dev.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try implementing them as class members:

```
public class Bingo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button b1;
    // more buttons here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bingo);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        // other findViewByIds here

    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        // do something with the buttons
    }
}
```

Comment: it isn't working! app crashes when i access buttons from show()